# submitting a form without hitting submit

Tags: jquery

I have a page, with a form that has hidden fields.

What I'm looking to do, is when the user hits the page, they get a 'Redirecting you....' and then the form is then submitted.

Can this be done using jQuery/PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Cannot be done with PHP, as PHP is only running on the server side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply submit the form:

```
 $('#FormID').submit();
```

If you want to do other UI stuff while the form is being submitted look at using AJAX to submit the form and update the UI.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

```
getElementById("frmID").submit();
```

Comment: Ended up using the jQuery equivelent: `$('#formId').submit();`